# How to build a project using the command line build step in TeamCity

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am quite new to continuous integration and also to TeamCity. For learning purposes I created a simple project containing some c files and pushed it to a github repo. Now, I want to use the command line build step option in teamcity to build the code. Something like : gcc test.c - o test or something. Obviously, this is not the correct command. How can I build the code using gcc with the command line option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use command line build runner.

See this image - How to use command line build runner :

[image]

Step 1: Select Runner Type - Command Line

Step 2: Select working directory

Step 3: Add your custom script

**Note:** First you have to install all the required dependence to run this scripts.

Let me know, If this works for you.